# Excessive logging after DXA 2.2.35 build update?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2, sites-9.5

A developer has reported that there is excessive application logging after updating to DXA build 2.2.35.  The environment is Sites 9.5, microservices are hosted by RWS.
`08:50:10.108 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-15] WARN  c.t.ambientdata.AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised`

I don't have a DXA (Java) application setup at the moment; has anyone run into this before and/or knows how to suppress this log warning?